# What is the difference between $|3|$ and $|\langle 6\rangle|$ when finding the order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is the difference between $|3|$ and $|\langle 6\rangle|$ when finding the order? Is it asking the same thing with or without $\langle \rangle$?

This is under $Z_{24}$.

I know that $|\langle 6\rangle| = \{0, 6, 12, 18\} = 4$

Would $|3| = \{0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21\} = 8$?

Answer (score 2):

$|3|$ is asking for the order of an element while $|<6>|$ is asking for the order of a subgroup (here it is the cyclic subgroup generated by $6$). In the case where the subgroup is generated one element, they are the same.

But I seldom see anyone using $|3|$ to represent the order of $3$.

By the way, the order of an element $a$ is the minimal positive number $n$ such that $na=0$ while the order of a subgroup is the cardinality of it.

Comment: Presumably you mean to write $na=0$ or $a^n=1$  there. You're mixing additive and multiplicative notation.

Comment: @Mike , Thanks, I've fixed it.